# dot graph in matplotlib is not uniform

Tags: matplotlib

Plotted using x and y coordinates but the graph is non uniform what should I do ?

```
    x_axis array(['115.0', '109.0', '99.0', '107.0', '108.0', '108.0', '87.0',
       '108.0', '105.0', '117.0', '102.0', '112.0', '115.0', '102.0',
       '108.0', '94.0', '108.0', '114.0', '115.0', '109.0', '117.0',
       '91.0', '118.0', '108.0', '111.0', '88.0', '113.0', '107.0',
       '110.0', '98.0', '113.0', '109.0', '102.0', '109.0'], dtype=object)
y_axis array([' 25.0', ' 51.0', ' 52.0', ' 40.0', ' 32.0', ' 32.0', ' 41.0',
       ' 36.0', ' 43.0', ' 53.0', ' 50.0', ' 39.0', ' 54.0', ' 34.0',
       ' 47.0', ' 54.0', ' 27.0', ' 34.0', ' 41.0', ' 39.0', ' 31.0',
       ' 52.0', ' 39.0', ' 35.0', ' 32.0', ' 34.0', ' 42.0', ' 47.0',
       ' 36.0', ' 46.0', ' 42.0', ' 52.0', ' 35.0', ' 37.0'], dtype=object)
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.plot(x_axis,y_axis,'ro')
    plt.show()
```

Output is [the y-axis is weird](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2nLf.png)

Answer (score 0):

The reason the y-axis number is all over the place is because it recognized the input data as a string instead of float. Notice that the order from bottom to top matches the order of the data in `y_axis array`

To fix that, remove `'` from the input data in that array, and possibbly remove that from `x_axis array` as well if you want that to be recognized as float.

Another way is to do string-to-float conversion of the data